# Python code for finding the total number of connected graphs that has a Cospectral and Coinvariant mates for several graph assosiated matrices

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a python code for finding the total number of connected graphs of order upto 10 that has a cospectral and coinvariant mates for several graph assosiated matrices. Two graphs are cospectral if they have the same spectrum and they are coinvariant if they have the same Smith Normal Form(SNF) with respect to adjacency matrix, laplacian matrix, distance matrix or any other graph assosiated matrices. The Smith normal form of a matrix is diagonal, and can be obtained from the original matrix by multiplying on the left and right by invertible square matrices.

Comment: Hi Usama -- while there may be people here versatile enough in coding to present an answer to your question, requests for code are nonstandard here. This is not to suggest that your question is necessarily out of place (particularly with the flavour of what you're trying to code), just a heads up that the subset of people here who can answer your question with code may be small. That being said, best of luck! (+1)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what this question is asking for. If you use existing packages/libraries to generate the graphs and the matrices, then you only need a few lines of code to do the bookkeeping. If you're writing code from scratch to generate the graphs, compute the matrices etc. then that would be much more tedious but not really a question of research-level mathematics.

Comment: You can use nauty software to build your requirement. nauty can be imported in sagemath, where you could code in python using standard python+sagemath libraries